# How to limit a string length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z_][\-_a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I need to limit it's length to 39 characters. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
^[a-zA-Z_][\-_a-zA-Z0-9]*{,38}
```

Comment: Side note: `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` has the same coverage as `\w`, so `[\-_a-zA-Z0-9]` can be replaced by `[-\w]`.

Comment: If this is on `<input>` use `maxlength` attribute if this is string, you can use `.length` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a limited quantifier `{0,38}` and an end of string anchor `$`:

```
^[a-zA-Z_][-_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,38}$
                       ^^^^^ ^
```

The syntax for the limited quantifiers is `{min,max}` where the `max` parameter is optional, but the minimum should be present. Without `$` you may match 39 first characters in a much longer string.

You do not have to escape a hyphen when it is placed at the beginning of a character class (thus, I suggest removing it).

Also, you can further shorten the regex with an `/i`modifier:

```
/^[a-z_][-_a-z0-9]{0,38}$/i
```

or even

```
/^[a-z_][-\w]{0,38}$/i
```

**Regarding the question from the comment:**

> wouldn't also that version work `(^[a-zA-Z_][-_a-zA-Z0-9]){0,39}$` with 39 characters limit?

The regex matches

- `(^[a-zA-Z_][-_a-zA-Z0-9]){0,39}` - 0 to 39 *sequences* of...

  - `^` - start of the string
  - `[a-zA-Z_]` - a single character from the specified range
  - `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]` - a single character from the specified range
- `$` - end of string

So, you require a match to include *sequences* from the start of the string. Note a start of string can be *matched* only once. As you let the number of such sequences to be 0, you only match either the location at the end of the string or a 2 character string like `A-`.

Let's see what the regex does with the [`Word` input](https://regex101.com/r/xA1lY7/2). It mathces the start of string with `^`, then `W` with `[a-zA-Z_]`, then `o` with `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]`. Then the group ends, and that equals to matching the group once. Since we can match more sequences, the regex tries to match `r` with `^`. It fails. So, the next position is retried and failed the same way, because `d` is not the `^` (start of string). And that way the end of string is matched because there is a 0 occurrences of `^[a-zA-Z_][-_a-zA-Z0-9]` and there is an end of string `$`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA1lY7/1)

Comment: thanks, wouldn't also that version work `(^[a-zA-Z_][-_a-zA-Z0-9]){0,39}$` with 39 characters limit?

Comment: Try it with [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/xA1lY7/1) - no, it will not, because the quantifier is set to the group that is anchored at the start of the string.

Comment: thanks, can you please elaborate on this a bit _the quantifier is set to the group that is anchored at the start of the string_?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
^[a-zA-Z_][\-_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,38}$
```

`[0,38]` means that number of instances of characters matching `[\-_a-zA-Z0-9]` could be 0 to 38.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this in case you're limiting input field entry.

While not regex, I use this function and it works well (I will add that it's important to let the user know you're limiting the input length from UI/UX point of view):

```
limitLength: function(element, lengthOf){
    var fieldLength = element.value.length;
    if(fieldLength <= lengthOf){
        return true;
    } else {
        var str = element.value;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        element.value = str;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" onInput="my.namespace.limitLength(this,39)">
```